# Print all equivalent string patterns for a given string, ? is optional

Tags: java, algorithm

For a given String lets say abc?de?, abcde, abcd, abde, abd are considered equivalent strings. A letter before a `?` is considered optional.

I need to write java code to print such equivalent patterns for any given string.

Examples:

**input**:
abc?de?

**Output**:
abcde, abcd, abde, abd

**input**:
abc?de?f?

**Output**:
abcde, abcd, abde, abd, abcdef, abcdf, abdef, abdf

How do i write a Java code to achieve this? Please help. I haven't used regular expressions much.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more because it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: So, are you basically looking for something like a inverse regex matcher, or do you just have those optional characters with a `?`?

Comment: _"I havent used regular expressions much"_. You're in luck :-) If all you have are alphabetical characters, and the `?` symbol which signifies an optional character, then this doesn't really have anything to do with regular expressions at all.

Comment: `abc?de?, abcde, abcd, abde, abd` how can they be equivalent?

Comment: Please show the effort you have undertaken to solve the problem on your own. We won't do your homework for you! ;)

Comment: What you want to do is a simplyfied (without 'x|y' and 'x*') regex matcher. Normaly you can create a NFA (with Thompson construction), transform it to a DFA, translate it into a graph and traversing the complete graph. Every edge of the graph stands for a character. So if you go from node A to B where there connected by an edge labeled by c, write c to the outgoing string.

Comment: Because alphabet before ? is optional.

Comment: An easy solution: split the string using `?` as the delimiter. `String[] array = string.split("?");`. This will leave the last letter of every String your target letter - the letter you want to be optional.

Comment: Then we have to extract two possibilities, with and without last character. and do a merge of all such strings?

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize how I understood the question: given a simplified regular expression (with only the ? operator available) enumerate all the strings matched by the expression.

You can solve this with a recursive approach: for the first ? in the pattern there are two possibilities: either the character before it is present or not. Both possibilities are followed by all the sub-strings matching the remainder of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it :) As I posted in my comment here is what I do:

1. Parse the input and determine if a character is optional or not
2. Create a graph of an DFA. The DFA contains a start node and a node for every character. The edges are labeled by the character. But it isn't really a DFA, because it hasn't a set of final states. (I noticed it after all was finished, so my trick is to add a "#" at the end. All leaf nodes in the graph can considered as final nodes)
3. Traverse the graph starting by the *start* node. Every visited edge adds its labeled character to a string. Every path from start to a leaf is a full string.

Here is the graph for `abc?de?`:

[image: Graph for abc?de?]

The string `abde` is highlighted. You can see that it has a path from start to a leaf.

Here is the complete source code:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class SimpleRegEx {
    private static final class InputCharacter {
        final char character;
        final boolean optional;

        public InputCharacter(final char character, final boolean optional) {
            this.character = character;
            this.optional = optional;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return character + (optional ? "?" : "");
        }
    }

    private static List<InputCharacter> parseRegEx(String input) {
        input = input + "#";
        final List<InputCharacter> characters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            final char character = input.charAt(i);
            final boolean eof = (i == input.length() - 1);
            final boolean optional = (!eof && input.charAt(i + 1) == '?');
            final InputCharacter inputCharacter = new InputCharacter(character,
                    optional);
            if (optional) {
                // Skip ?
                i++;
            }
            characters.add(inputCharacter);
        }
        return characters;
    }

    private static final class Graph {
        final Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<>();

        void dump() {
            System.out.println("{");
            for (final Edge e : edges) {
                System.out.println("\t" + e.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }

    private static final class Node {
        final String label;

        public Node(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + label + ")";
        }
    }

    private static final class Edge {
        final Node from;
        final Node to;
        final char label;

        public Edge(final Node from, final Node to, final char label) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%s)-%s->(%s)", from.label, this.label,
                    to.label);
        }
    }

    private static Graph constructGraph(
            final List<InputCharacter> inputCharacters) {
        final Graph graph = new Graph();

        final Node start = new Node("start");
        graph.nodes.add(start);
        if (inputCharacters.isEmpty()) {
            return graph;
        }

        final Map<InputCharacter, Node> nodes = new IdentityHashMap<>(
                inputCharacters.size());

        // Create a node for every input character
        for (int i = 0, n = inputCharacters.size(); i < n; i++) {
            final Node node = new Node("s" + i);
            nodes.put(inputCharacters.get(i), node);
            graph.nodes.add(node);
        }

        // Create an edge to each reachable node
        for (int i = 0, n = inputCharacters.size(); i < n; i++) {
            final InputCharacter fromChar = inputCharacters.get(i);
            final Node fromNode = nodes.get(fromChar);

            int j = i + 1;
            while (true) {
                if (j >= n) {
                    break;
                }

                final InputCharacter toChar = inputCharacters.get(j);
                final Node toNode = nodes.get(toChar);
                final Edge edge = new Edge(fromNode, toNode, toChar.character);
                graph.edges.add(edge);

                j++;
                if (j >= n || !toChar.optional) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Create an edge from start to all reachable first nodes
        int i = 0;
        do {
            final InputCharacter toChar = inputCharacters.get(i);
            final Node toNode = nodes.get(toChar);
            final Edge edge = new Edge(start, toNode, toChar.character);
            graph.edges.add(edge);
            i++;
            if (i >= inputCharacters.size() || !inputCharacters.get(i).optional) {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        return graph;
    }

    private static Set<String> computeAllStrings(final Graph graph) {
        // Find start node by name (start node should stored explicity)
        Node start = null;
        for (final Node n : graph.nodes) {
            if ("start".equals(n.label)) {
                start = n;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (start == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("Expected start node exists");
        }

        final Set<String> stringsBefore = traverse(graph, start, "");
        final Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>(stringsBefore.size());
        for (final String s : stringsBefore) {
            // Trim last #
            strings.add(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
        }
        return strings;
    }

    private static Set<String> traverse(final Graph graph, final Node n,
            final String prefix) {
        final Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<Edge> outgoingEdges = getAllOutgoingEdges(graph, n);
        final boolean leaf = outgoingEdges.isEmpty();
        if (leaf) {
            strings.add(prefix);
            return strings;
        }

        for (final Edge e : outgoingEdges) {
            final String newPrefix = prefix + e.label;
            strings.addAll(traverse(graph, e.to, newPrefix));
        }
        return strings;
    }

    private static Set<Edge> getAllOutgoingEdges(final Graph graph, final Node n) {
        final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<>();
        for (final Edge e : graph.edges) {
            if (e.from == n) {
                edges.add(e);
            }
        }
        return edges;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "abc?de?";
        final List<InputCharacter> characters = parseRegEx(input);
        System.out.println("Input:");
        System.out.println(characters);
        System.out.println();

        final Graph graph = constructGraph(characters);
        System.out.println("Graph:");
        graph.dump();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Strings:");
        for (final String s : computeAllStrings(graph)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Input:
[a, b, c?, d, e?, #]

Graph:
{
    (s3)-#->(s5)
    (s1)-c->(s2)
    (s0)-b->(s1)
    (start)-a->(s0)
    (s3)-e->(s4)
    (s1)-d->(s3)
    (s2)-d->(s3)
    (s4)-#->(s5)
}

Strings:
abd
abcd
abde
abcde
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler version. It turns out that te construction of the graph is not neccessary because the traversing can done implicit by executing a recursive function:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

public class SimpleRegEx {
    private static final class InputCharacter {
        final char character;
        final boolean optional;

        public InputCharacter(final char character, final boolean optional) {
            this.character = character;
            this.optional = optional;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return character + (optional ? "?" : "");
        }
    }

    private static List<InputCharacter> parseRegEx(final String input) {
        final List<InputCharacter> characters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            final char character = input.charAt(i);
            final boolean eof = (i == input.length() - 1);
            final boolean optional = (!eof && input.charAt(i + 1) == '?');
            final InputCharacter inputCharacter = new InputCharacter(character,
                    optional);
            if (optional) {
                // Skip ?
                i++;
            }
            characters.add(inputCharacter);
        }
        return characters;
    }

    private static Set<String> computeAllStrings(
            final List<InputCharacter> characters) {
        if (characters.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        final InputCharacter first = characters.get(0);
        final List<InputCharacter> rest = restOfList(characters);
        return step(first, rest);
    }

    private static Set<String> step(final InputCharacter c,
            final List<InputCharacter> rest) {
        final Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
        if (rest.isEmpty()) {
            strings.add(String.valueOf(c.character));
            if (c.optional) {
                strings.add("");
            }
            return strings;
        }

        final InputCharacter next = rest.get(0);
        final List<InputCharacter> nextRest = restOfList(rest);
        final Set<String> suffixes = step(next, nextRest);

        for (final String s : suffixes) {
            strings.add(c.character + s);
        }

        if (c.optional) {
            strings.addAll(suffixes);
        }

        return strings;
    }

    private static <T> List<T> restOfList(final List<T> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else if (list.size() == 1) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            return list.subList(1, list.size());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "abc?de?";
        final List<InputCharacter> characters = parseRegEx(input);
        System.out.println("Input:");
        System.out.println(characters);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Strings:");
        for (final String s : computeAllStrings(characters)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```